# Change icon order in Unity 2d in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: unity-2d

How do you rearrange the order of icons in the dock in Unity 2D in Ubuntu 11.10?  I searched and saw a post that said the order can be changed by pulling the icon to the right and dragging it, but I think that might have been for the regular Unity because it does not seem to work for me.  I see that I can remove items from the dock, but what I want to do is move Chrome and Terminal to the top.  I'm sure it's possible, but it's surprising that such a simple task seems so hard.  I assume I must be overlooking something easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really simple. You have to click on the icon and take it pressed for one second or so and then drag it directly up or down over the other icons, without going to the right or out of the dock..the tutorial you saw is strictly for Unity 3D..